# Telerik <RadCombo> on first selection of any item other than first is always resetting to first item

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

Telerik  on first selection of any item other than first is always resetting to first item and it does not fire the selectedindexchange event. However, when the combobox is selected for a second time, the event fires.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Right it only fires when the item changes, so first item is not technically a change of the selection since it defaults to zero.  A workaround is to add a default blank item, and force a selection through the RequiredFieldValidator control.

Comment: If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim objCommodity As New Commodity
            objCommodity.MyUserInfoId = intUserInfoId
            objCommodity.MyClientId = intMyClientID
            objCommodity.LoadUserCommodities()

            drpCommodity.DataTextField = "commodity_type"
            drpCommodity.DataValueField = "commodity_type_id"
            drpCommodity.DataSource = objCommodity
            drpCommodity.DataBind()
            drpCommodity.Items.Insert(0, New RadComboBoxItem    ("Select", String.Empty))
        End If
         drpCommodity.SelectedItem.Text = "Cable"

Comment: What does LoadUserCommunities do?  You're binding a singular object to the combobox so that isn't going to work right.  You need to bind the user commodities, like drpCommodity.DataSource = objCommodity.UserCommodities, or call some method that returns a list.